# I am having a hard time understanding what I have done wrong in making this calculator

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an area calculator but I think I messed something up with defining the length and width.
I get an error saying error: uninitialized const 'length' [-fpermissive]| (same thing with the width)
I'm new to programming

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const char length;
const char width;
cout << "Please enter the your length: ";
cin >> length;
cout << "Please enter your width: ";
cin >> width;
string area =
    length * width;
cout << " The area of these values is :" << area << "\n";
}
```

Comment: There are multiple errors, but that error specifically is telling you not to declare something `const` without also giving it a value on the same line (in this case you probably want to remove `const` from the declaration).

Comment: @NickRomano that's because you are trying to implicitly convert a number to a `std::string`. That won't work. Just make it `int area = length * width;` (edit: oh well, his comment under the answer used to be here)

Answer (score 0):

> `cin >> length;`

Are you sure about variable declarations like `const char length;`
`const` actually indicates, you can't change these *variable values*, and trying to do so is undefined behavior.

Also note `length` should be of type [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), not just `unsigned char`, which is only able to hold up a size of 255 maximum.

Comment: I originally put it as int and that didn't work. It says the problem with the code is in the line that says: length * width

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declarations of length and width shouldn't be `const`. The error you're getting is because `const` values need to be initialized (have a value assigned to them) when they are declared. They cannot have a value assigned to them which is what `cin >>` does.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry I wasn't thinking. I originally had it int instead of const but I understand what I screwed up. Thanks!

Comment: `const` is a qualifier you use to say that your variable cannot be changed. `const double pi = 3.14;` would be an example of when it is appropriate. The compiler would then replace each occurrence of `pi` in your code with it's actual value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char length;    // Making these const will break as soon as you try to write to it
    const char width;     //
    cout << "Please enter the your length: ";
    cin >> length;   // The fact you made it a char means it will only read the first char. "10" it would read "1"
    cout << "Please enter your width: ";
    cin >> width;
    string area =    // this will not work. There is no assignment operator for char to string 
        length * width;   
    cout << " The area of these values is :" << area << "\n";
}
```

Fixed

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float length;
    float width;
    cout << "Please enter the your length: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Please enter your width: ";
    cin >> width;
    float area = length * width;
    cout << " The area of these values is :" << area << "\n";
}
```